# Automatically delete 'old' data sets in Django - MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a sensor node that is streaming environmental data every 5 minutes (temperature, pH) along with its battery levels to a MYSQL instance (and a Django App). Now, I will store all logged temperature , pH data indefinitely on the db as they stream in, but would like to limit battery-level data storage to up to 3 months only. Reason being, its not an important metric for historical data analytics and there is hence no point on taking up disk space, especially if there are multiple nodes sending in data like this.

Think of my models.py that deal with this battery level data as something like...

```
class Node_Health(models.Model):
     # Battery levels, in percentage to two decimal placing
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True,auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True) # db index
     battery_lvl = models.CharField(max_length=4,null=True)
```

Question is, How do I (best practice) automatically monitor & discard of 'old' battery level data once the battery level logs reach > 3 months in the Django-python framework ? i.e. store only the latest three months of battery levels in db. Do i use CRON or Celery with a python script that checks the db for any data in excess and wipes out these 'old data' ? (this is the only way i Know, which may not be the better way to do it)... I am certainly not an expert in db and dev-ops ; would appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use **MYSQL Event Scheduler**. MySQL Events are tasks that run according to a `schedule`. Therefore, we sometimes refer to them as **scheduled events**. When you create an event, you are creating a named database object containing one or more SQL statements to be executed at one or more regular intervals, beginning and ending at a specific date and time. Conceptually, this is similar to the idea of the Unix crontab (also known as a “cron job”) or the Windows Task Scheduler.

References:

- [MYSQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html)
- [Celery beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) is a periodic scheduler, you can also try that too.

Notes:

1. I'm not sure which is the more reliable method to achieve your requirement
2. **MySQL Event Scheduler** is only available from version `5.1.6`

Comment: Thanks Jerin, I looked into this and I'm goona give the MYSQL event scheduler a shot during alpha and see how it pans out. Good info!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a CRON job for this kind of task.

I would set it up just the way you described it.

Comment: Thanks Ralf =) Good to know that my initial thoughts may not be so far off afterall..